# Why is onpropertychange not working for me?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, internet-explorer-9

I am in IE 9 and I call:

```
document.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(){
    console.log("triggered");
});
```

in the console which returns `true`.

Then I change an attribute:

```
$('div').eq(0).attr("data-url", "url");
```

which changes the attribute but does not print `triggered` to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this event does not bubble, so placing the handler on the `document` wouldn't observe property changes on `div` elements.

[image]

Also, I'm not certain that a change to a sub property of `element.dataset` would trigger the hander. Worth testing I suppose.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with your first statement: "Note  Changing the innerText or innerHTML of child elements will not cause the onpropertychange event to fire for the parent element."

Comment: can you override default options so that it bubbles?

Comment: @user730569: Those aren't options. They're descriptions of the behavior of the event type, so they can't be changed.

Comment: crap, so if I want to listen to attribute changes on all elements in IE, I would need to loop through the DOM and attach the event to each one?

Comment: @user730569: It would seem that way. Be aware that this listens for *property* changes, not *attribute* changes. Some attribute changes also update properties, but some don't. If you do bind to each, you can use a named function created outside the loop, so that you're keeping the memory overhead to a minimum.

Comment: Right, makes sense. @TravisJ just noticed that it does not work with changing text... is there any functionality (besides polling) that listens for this in IE?

Comment: Also, how far back does `onpropertychange` work in terms of IE versions?

Comment: @user730569: Not sure how far back it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try attaching this event to all of your divs like this:

```
var divs = $('div');
$.each(divs, function(divObj){
 divObj.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(){
  console.log("triggered");
 });
});
```